# The Linux Kernel container_of macro and generic containers in C90

Tags: c, data-structures, linux-kernel, typeof, c89

Is it possible to implement the [container_of](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/tools/perf/util/include/linux/kernel.h#L18) macro in pure C90?  I'm not sure how to do it as the Kernel implementation depends on [GCC Hacks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gcc-hacks/index.html) such as the `typeof` operator.

I'm asking because I would like to implement a generic container in C90 similar to the Kernel's [linked list](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/include/linux/list.h#L24).  The actual container I'm thinking of is a sequenced set similar to what you might get from [Boost MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The use of `typeof` in the kernel definition of `container_of()` is just for compile-time type-checking - it ensures that the passed `ptr` is really a pointer to the same type as `member`.  It can be modified to be entirely ANSI C at the cost of this type-checking:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ((type *)((char *)ptr - offsetof(type, member)))
```

(`offsetof()` is in `<stddef.h>`)

Comment: actually, typesafe variant can be implemented in C89. See the other answer

Comment: @tstanisl: Agreed, I like your answer a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
The trick is replacing compound expression and `typeof` used for type checking. It can be done by replacing evaluation of `(ptr)` with:

```
(1 ? (ptr) : &((type*)0)->member)
```

A conditional operator always returns the first operand because its selection operand is 1. The other operand is *not evaluated*, therefore there is no UB due to `NULL` dereferencing. Moreover, the types of operands of `?:` have to be compatible forcing type checking from a compiler.

The final macro is:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member)          \
  ((type*)((char*)(1 ? (ptr) : &((type*)0)->member) - offsetof(type, member)))
```

This macro is even *better* than the original `container_of`.

The C89 variant can be used at file scope or for initialization of static variables, while the Linux one cannot.