# How to correctly downcast in C?

Tags: c, c17

I'm currently limited to coding in C and I want to do C object oriented programming.

One thing that comes to mind is how to correctly downcast a type in C without violating strict aliasing.

Imagine I have an animal struct with a vtable (meaning a struct of function pointers) and a dog like this:

```
typedef void (*sound_func)(const animal_t *animal);

struct animal_vtable {
    sound_func sound;
};
typedef struct animal_vtable animal_vtable_t;

typedef struct animal {
    animal_vtable_t * vtable;
    int size;
} animal_t;

typedef struct dog {
    animal_t animal;
} dog_t;
```

There will be cases when I want to know whether my animal is a dog, this is how I currently think of making an animal instance a dog, but I'm unsure if this will trigger undefined behavior or not.

```
dog_t *to_dog(animal_t *a) {
    if (a->vtable != &dog_table) {
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t offset = offsetof(dog_t, animal);
    uintptr_t animal_offset = (uintptr_t) a;
    return (dog_t *) (animal_offset - offset);
}
```

The key part here is that both the memory of `dog_t *` and `animal_t *` are on the same memory location for obvious reasons, but will this be a problem for optimizers? Currently I have `-fno-strict-aliasing`
enabled and thus I know it works, but is it safe to turn that off?

Below is the full working example which does not trigger errors when compiled with address and unefined behavior sanitizers.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * Animal section
 */
struct animal_vtable;
typedef struct animal_vtable animal_vtable_t;

typedef struct animal {
    animal_vtable_t * vtable;
    int size;
} animal_t;


typedef void (*sound_func)(const animal_t *animal);

struct animal_vtable {
    sound_func sound;
};

void animal_sound(const animal_t* animal) {
    animal->vtable->sound(animal);
}

int animal_size(const animal_t* animal) {
    return animal->size;
}


/*
 * dog section
 */
void dog_bark(const animal_t *animal);

static animal_vtable_t dog_table = {
    .sound = dog_bark
};

typedef struct dog {
    animal_t animal;
} dog_t;

dog_t* make_dog(int size) {
    dog_t* dog = malloc(sizeof(dog_t));
    if (dog == NULL) {
        return dog;
    }
    dog->animal = (animal_t) { .vtable = &dog_table, .size = size };
    return dog;
}

void dog_bark(const animal_t *animal) {
    printf("wuff!\n");
}

dog_t *to_dog(animal_t *a) {
    if (a->vtable != &dog_table) {
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t offset = offsetof(dog_t, animal);
    uintptr_t animal_offset = (uintptr_t) a;
    return (dog_t *) animal_offset - offset;
}

/*
 * main tests
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    dog_t *dog = make_dog(10);
    if (dog == NULL) {
        exit(-1);

    }
    animal_t *animal = &(dog->animal);
    
    animal_sound(animal);

    dog_t *d2 = to_dog(animal);
    printf("dog addr: %p, d2 addr: %p\n", dog, d2);
    printf("dog size: %d\n", animal_size(&d2->animal));
    printf("dog size: %d\n", animal_size(&dog->animal));

    free(dog);

}
```

Comment: What is an `animal_vtable_t` and what is the meaning of it?

Comment: I do not see any OO programming here, only hard to understand code doing basically nothing

Comment: Please include an implementation of `animal_vtable_t`

Comment: At least in the C99 standard, which I use, only casts of operands with scalar types are permitted (no structs).

Comment: How "static" is your type hierarchy? Can't you use a union?

Comment: It looks that you need `container_of` macro

Comment: @tstanisl I'm more asking if container_of can be implemented in a compliant way, or I'm forcing myself out of iso C17. but yeah it goes in the right direction.

Comment: @AlexanderOh, yes, it can. See my two posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72403103/4989451  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405672/4989451

Comment: @tstanisl thanks. have your two upvotes on the questions! it helped alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm unsure if this will trigger undefined behavior or not.
>
> ```
> dog_t *to_dog(animal_t *a) {
>     if (a->vtable != &dog_table) {
>         return NULL;
>     }
>     size_t offset = offsetof(dog_t, animal);
>     uintptr_t animal_offset = (uintptr_t) a;
>     return (dog_t *) animal_offset - offset;
> }
> ```

The expression `(dog_t *) animal_offset - offset` does not mean what you think it means.  It is equivalent to `((dog_t *) animal_offset) - offset`, whereas what you appear to want is `(dog_t *) (animal_offset - offset)` (and these are different).

But more generally, you are making it harder than it needs to be.  Supposing that you implement inheritance as you seem inclined to do, by making the first member of the child type an instance of the parent type, you can perform the kind of pointer conversion you demonstrate via a simple cast: `(dog_t *) a`.  The language specification guarantees that this is valid under the conditions described, supposing that `a` is in fact a pointer to the `animal` member of a `dog_t`.  This is specified in C17, paragraph 6.7.2.1/15 (emphasis added):

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in
> which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in
> which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure object, suitably
> converted, points to its initial member** (or if that member is a
> bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), **and vice versa.**
> There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
> beginning.

Substantially the same wording appears in earlier versions of the standard, too.

As for

> will this be a problem for optimizers? Currently I have
> -fno-strict-aliasing enabled and thus I know it works, but is it safe to turn that off?

It should not be a problem for optimizers, *provided that the definition of `dog_t` is visible in the translation unit*.  In that case, optimizers that are not deeply broken will know that pointers to `dog_t` and pointers to `animal_t` can alias each other.

However, the definition of `dog_t` being visible is a requirement for use of `offsetof`, but *not* a requirement for the pointer cast, so that may be something to watch out for.  Also, it's not just this code where you need to watch out for aliasing issues.  For safety relative to strict aliasing, *every* function that accesses pointers to both types will need to have the definition of `dog_t` visible.

Comment: Furthermore, we are supposed to be able to use an exotic rule called _common initial sequence_, to inspect not just the first member of a struct, but a sequence of identical members. Take for example something like `struct dog { animal_t a; size_t size; ..` vs `struct cat { animal_t a; size_t size; ..`. The C standard says that if we create a union somewhere in the translation unit containing both "dog" and "cat", it will be well-defined to inspect their common initial sequence - in this case also the `size` members. Compilers supposedly have shaky support for this standard C feature though.

Comment: That is, it would be valid to cast a `dog*` to a `cat*` and then access `cat->size`. This might be handy when implementing inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: @Lundin, although unions and the common initial sequence rule can play in this space, the rule has more limited scope than your comments seem to imply.  It is applicable only when there is an object of the union type, only while that union object actually contains an object of one of the types (`dog`, `cat`, ...) whose common initial sequence is to be accessed.  Although not explicitly stated, I also take it to be implied that the common initial sequence rule applies only to accessing the object in the union, not generally to all objects of the types involved.

Comment: An in-scope declaration of such a union does mean that the compiler *should* recognize the aliasing possibilities, but it does not formally provide a blanket exemption from the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: The standard says "it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible" which can be interpreted in several different ways. There were some defect reports about this rule, iirc since some thought it only applied to a union object and compilers implemented it differently. The (informative) examples in the standard suggests otherwise however - it's sufficient if the union definition (completed type) is present.

Comment: @Lundin, the context of that statement is "if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains
one of these structures [...]".  The relevant example would be example 3 (paragraph 6.5.2.3/9), which does not counterindicate my interpretation.  It designates the union declaration being out of scope as the reason for the code presented being invalid, but the two pointers involved in fact do point to different members of the same union object, so *that* requirement is satisfied.